# Simple VBA: Calc an Array Formula or 255 Char Limit Workaround?

Tags: vba, excel

I need a .FormulaArray inserted into my worksheet, however it is well over the 255 character limit (it's 420). I've tried the `.Replace` workaround, but it doesn't work. Using `.Formula =` will get it into the cell, but it doesn't calculate and produces `#VALUE!`, so I would have to `crtl+shift+Enter` manually. Is there a way VBA can replicate this?

```
.Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Red Car", .Range("A:A"), 0), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ComboBox1.Value & " " & Year(Date), .Range("A6:BZ6"), 0)).FormulaArray = "=INDEX('" & Root & sourceSheet & ws.Name & " " & "SUM" & " " & monthNumber & "." & lastDay & "." & Format(Now(), "yy") & "'!$D:$D,MATCH(""Dealer1"",'" & Root & sourceSheet & ws.Name & " " & "SUM" & " " & monthNumber & "." & lastDay & "." & Format(Now(), "yy") & "'!$A:$A&'" & Root & sourceSheet & ws.Name & " " & "SUM" & " " & monthNumber & "." & lastDay & "." & Format(Now(), "yy") & "'!$B:$B,0))"
```

The .Replace setup I'm using is:

```
Dim theFormulaPart1 As String
Dim theFormulaPart2 As String

theFormulaPart1 = "=INDEX('" & Root & sourceSheet & ws.Name & " " & "SUM" & " " & monthNumber & "." & lastDay & "." & Format(Now(), "yy") & "'!$D:$D,MATCH(""Dealer1"",'" & Root & sourceSheet & ws.Name & " " & "X_X_X())"
theFormulaPart2 = "&" & "SUM" & " " & monthNumber & "." & lastDay & "." & Format(Now(), "yy") & "'!$A:$A&'" & Root & sourceSheet & ws.Name & " " & "SUM" & " " & monthNumber & "." & lastDay & "." & Format(Now(), "yy") & "'!$B:$B,0))"    

.Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Red Car", .Range("A:A"), 0), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ComboBox1.Value & " " & Year(Date), .Range("A6:BZ6"), 0)).FormulaArray = theFormulaPart1
.Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Red Car", .Range("A:A"), 0), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ComboBox1.Value & " " & Year(Date), .Range("A6:BZ6"), 0)).Reaplce "X_X_X())", theFormulaPart2
```

Comment: The replace workaround works for me, why doesn't it work for you?

Comment: How can I set up the replace formula? When I set it up  into Dim theFormulaPart1 and Dim theFormulaPart2, i still get the same range error

Comment: Are you aware you used `Reaplce` at last line ?

Comment: Is that not the correct way to do this? The last line is just a reference to the target cell, then .Reaplce "X_X_X())", theFormulaPart2

Comment: Reaplce -> Replace

Comment: But it still wont work. You cannot break the formula in two parts in whatever way you want. The first part and the final part need to be **syntactically correct**, which they aren't.

Comment: @A.S.H this is the problem i am currently facing. How else can I get excel to calculate that cell?

Comment: Problem is that your initial formula seems to me ill-formed as well. Why dont you try first to generate a string, debug.print it, then copy it from the immediate window to Excel (and press Ctlr+Shift+Enter). **Debug it**. After that, we can find a way to pass it through the `.FormulaArray` method by working around the size limit.

Comment: What is `Root` by the way? a possible workaround would be to open the `sourceSheet` and use only `[TheWorkbookName]` in the formula, that will shorten it a lot and it might pass easily.